# Casting from msg.sender address to a Contract compiles but causes test failure

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I have the following simple contracts:

```
contract HasOwner {
    address public owner;

    function HasOwner() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

and

```
import './HasOwner';

contract Mudhoney is HasOwner {
    function Mudhoney() HasOwner() public {}
}
```

and

```
import './HasOwner';
import './Mudhoney';

contract Melvin is HasOwner {

    event FoundJustice(Mudhoney mudhoney);

    function Melvin() HasOwner() public {}

    function foundJustice() external {
        Mudhoney mudhoney = Mudhoney(msg.sender);
        FoundJustice(mudhoney);
    }
}
```

deployed via migration to Truffle's internal testnet:

```
const Mudhoney = artifacts.require('./Mudhoney.sol')
const Melvin = artifacts.require('./Melvin.sol')

const migrate = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  deployer.deploy(Mudhoney, { from: accounts[0] }).then(() => {
    console.log('Deployed Mudhoney with address', Mudhoney.address, 'from address', accounts[0])
  })

  deployer.deploy(Melvin, { from: accounts[1] }).then(() => {
    console.log('Deployed Melvin with address', Melvin.address, 'from address', accounts[1])
  })
}

module.exports = migrate
```

and tested via

```
const Mudhoney = artifacts.require('./Mudhoney.sol')

contract('Mudhoney', (accounts) => {
  const tester = accounts[0]

  it('is owned', () => Mudhoney.deployed()
    .then(instance => instance.owner())
    .then((owner) => {
      assert.equal(owner, tester, `Expected the owner to be '${tester}'`)
    }))
})


const Melvin = artifacts.require('./Melvin.sol')

contract('Melvin', (accounts) => {
  const tester = accounts[1]

  it('is owned', () => Melvin.deployed()
    .then(instance => instance.owner())
    .then((owner) => {
      assert.equal(owner, tester, `Expected the owner to be '${tester}'`)
    }))
})
```

The test of `Mudhoney` passes just fine but the test of `Melvin` fails

```
1) Contract: Melvin is owned:
   Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs (/Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43290:16)
    at SolidityFunction.validateArgs (/Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329512:22)
    at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329528:10)
    at SolidityFunction.call (/Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329569:24)
    at SolidityFunction.execute (/Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:329698:22)
    at /Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:318032:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/davesag/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:318023:18
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

After some trial and error I discovered that the Solidity function it's complaining about is the casting `Mudhoney mudhoney = Mudhoney(msg.sender)` in `Melvin`'s `foundJustice` function.

Why is that not working, and why does the test even care given it's not trying to execute the `foundJustice` function but the `owner` function.

Comment: That is odd because you never call foundJustice in your test! Since you are using truffle I'd try recompiling all your contracts (ie rename the build/ folder, and run truffle compile). I've seen very nasty bugs, mostly because truffle gets confused with a corrupted artifact.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael nuking the `build` folder and recompiling worked and now my tests all pass.  I'll pass this on to the Truffle people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Ismael in the comment above, it turned out that my issue was a bug in Truffle itself. The solution was rather than expect `compile --all` to work, was to nuke my `build` folder and then rerun `compile`.  Then `migrate --reset` and, voila, `test` ran perfectly.

The [Truffle project](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases) also has just released a `.1` release that fixes a number of bugs, and since upgrading to `4.0.1` I am unable to reproduce the original issue.